# Test ansible playbooks for deprecated syntax against a specific version

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible

I inherited some legacy code from a different team.

These ansible playbooks run fine with current version of ansible 2.3 but they make use of syntax which is way old and has few syntax which was deprecated in older versions 1.6 !!!

So I want to upgrade it to adopt to the latest version, in order to take advantage of some new features of ansible.

Now since ansible has not still removed the deprecated syntax, is there a way so that i can run in strict mode so that it treats deprecated syntax as unsupported. This way I can identify all the deprecated lines as well as I can run a sanity test.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of such feature in Ansible.

There's `--syntax-check` option for `ansible-playbook`, but this doesn't show deprecation warnings as they occur in runtime.

You can patch your Ansible installation a bit.
Add `removed = True` at the very beginning of `display.deprecated` method [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L186).
This way Ansible will treat every deprecated feature as removed one and raise fatal error.

Comment: this somewhat serves the purpose. I will try this. Thanks.